# Realm, Swift and App Sandbox not working?

Tags: swift, macos, realm

I can't get Realm (lastest version), Swift and Sandboxing to work.

I created a Hello Word app with RealmSwift / Realm embedded binaries included correctly.

```
import RealmSwift
```

..add one class and only the line:

```
let realm = try! Realm ()
```

Then I got this error when I run the app:

```
*2016-08-17 21:04:05.404 testprosjekt1[37407:21624950] ***storageTaskManagerExistsWithIdentifier:withIdentifier failed: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.nsurlstorage-cache was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.nsurlstorage-cache was invalidated.}; {
    NSDebugDescription = "The connection to service named com.apple.nsurlstorage-cache was invalidated.";
}
2016-08-17 21:04:05.412 testprosjekt1[37407:21624950] ***cachedResponseDictionaryForRequest:key:handler failed: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.nsurlstorage-cache was invalidated." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.nsurlstorage-cache was invalidated.}; {
    NSDebugDescription = "The connection to service named com.apple.nsurlstorage-cache was invalidated.";*
}
```

If I turn off sandboxing - I got NO error at all.
So, my question is: Is the latest version of Realm NOT working with sandboxed apps?

- I have tried set Read / write on to all the directories in sandboxing, but this does not help.
- I use xCode 7.3

Comment: I have a feeling that Realm might create some cache / tempoary files outside the restriced sandbox folders??
If this is true, this is a major case if you can't create OS X app with Realm for the App Store on OS X (MacOs).
I hope this is not true ..

Answer (score 1):

Realm works well with sandboxing (until you try to reader or write to a directory you don't have access to).

Realm collects anonymous analytics and checks for updates when your app is run with a debugger attached, or when it runs in a simulator. This call does not run when your app is in production, or running on your user’s devices. See more at [FAQ](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#i-see-a-network-call-to-mixpanel-when-i-run-my-app-what-is-that).

Also if you perform any network calls in your app add `com.apple.security.network.client` to your entitlement (or simply enable `Outgoing connection (Client)` in `Capabilities` tab of your project's settings).